# VS Code, Powershell and using user modules

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

Good day.

First of all, sorry about my English.

If you add the use of a custom module in the code
PowerShell VSCode

```
using module. \ modules \ lineNumber.psm1
```

it is loaded at the first start of the script and judging by what I see, the subsequent call of the script with "using module. \ modules \ lineNumber.psm1" does not load it.
Features arise when you make changes to this module, they are not perceived by the script that called the module until you restart the terminal.

Actually the question is, how to configure VS Code so that every script launch it does in a new terminal session?
Or any other workaround for this feature.

testmodule.psm1

```
class foo {
    static [string] rv () {
        return "b"
    }
}
```

console:

```
PS C:\Repository\alHaos\sandbox> cd .\modules\
PS C:\Repository\alHaos\sandbox\modules> using module .\testmodule.psm1
PS C:\Repository\alHaos\sandbox\modules> [foo]::rv()
b
# here i change the line 'return "b"' in the file .\testmodule.psm1 to "return "c""
PS C:\Repository\alHaos\sandbox\modules> using module .\testmodule.psm1
PS C:\Repository\alHaos\sandbox\modules> [foo]::rv()
b
# but here still 'b'
```

then i restart console and gеt 'c'

```
PS C:\Users\alhaos> cd C:\Repository\alHaos\sandbox\modules\
PS C:\Repository\alHaos\sandbox\modules> using module .\testmodule.psm1
PS C:\Repository\alHaos\sandbox\modules> [foo]::rv()
c
```

Comment: my understanding is that you MUST remove the previous version of the module and then load the modified version. you may be able to use `-force`, but i have never tested that.

Comment: kool! glad to help ... and that you got things working as needed ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restart the PowerShell session each script run in Visual Studio Code, you can configure *Create Temporary Integrated Console* setting in PowerShell extension:

```
"powershell.debugging.createTemporaryIntegratedConsole": true
```

[image]